# JQuery UI: Bounce animation queuing but stop() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the bounce animation from JQuery UI:

```
$('.mydiv').mouseover(function () {
      $(this).effect("bounce", { times:4 }, 300);
});
```

And I have the old problem of the animation 'queuing' if I hover over them (ie: if I move the mouse over a div rapidly 4 times the animation will occur one after the over 4 times).

Normally I would use `.stop()` to deal with it, eg:

```
$('.mydiv').mouseover(function () {
      $(this).stop().effect("bounce", { times:4 }, 300);
});
```

But in this instance it doesnt make any difference. Does anyone know of a solution?

Using `.stop(true)` means the animations stop witout completing the bounce like so:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`:animated` selector](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) with the [`.is()` method](http://api.jquery.com/is) to test if the element already has an animation in progress. If so, don't start the bounce:

```
$('.mydiv').mouseover(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.is(":animated"))
      $this.effect("bounce", { times:4 }, 300);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) accepts two paramters, both of which default to false.

There's param1, or `clearQueue` --which will clear all other animations behind it from the queue and stop the animation in it's track.

Then there's param2, or `jumpToEnd` - which will finish the animation immediately.

if you set `.stop(true)` It should work as intended.

Comment: thanks - but now the animtaion stops midway through, meaning the icons  stop out of alignment. Ive attached an image above to demonstrate

Comment: perhaps you want to finish the animation immediately, then, `.stop(false, true);`

Comment: Im afraid adding that returns me to square one - the animations start queuing again

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's impossible to stop (finish) and dequeue jQueryUI (but not core jQuery) animation with .stop() if it is only... not used twice. :)

It's just a "trick" to change the order of what it performs. So, try this:

`$('button').on('click', function(){
    $(this).stop(false, true).stop(true, false).animate('bounce')
});`